# Question about clausal form

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

The propositional logic textbook I'm working through explains how to convert a formula in conjunctive normal form to clausal form, for instance:

**((p ∨ ¬p ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r)) ∧ ((p ∨ ¬p ∨ q) ∧ (¬r ∨ ¬p ∨ q))**

has a clausal form of:

**{{¬p, ¬q, r}, {¬p, q, ¬r}}**

What I'm unsure about is why there are only 2 sets, and not 4 sets, as there are 4 conjuncts in the CNF formula. For instance, I would expect the following to be the clausal form for the formula:

**{{r}, {¬p, ¬q, r}, {q}, {¬p, q, ¬r}}**

Furthermore, the following examples are provided:

1. **(¬p ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ p)** equates to **{{¬p}, {p}}**, which I understand
2. **(¬p ∨ p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ p ∨ q)** equates to **∅**, which I don't quite understand - there can't be duplicate sets, but surely 1 of the instances can be present in the clausal form? I would expect the clausal form to be the following: **{{q}}**
3. **(¬p ∨ p) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ p)** equates to **{{¬p, q}}**, which I don't quite understand - why are all the clauses put into 1 set, and not into separate sets, as with example 1 above? I would expect the clausal form to be the following: **{{¬p, q}, {¬q}}**

Clearly I'm missing something here. The textbook unfortunately does not explain the conversion process in a lot of detail, so I'm getting a bit lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any conjunct that contains $p \lor \lnot p$ is automatically true and can thus be omitted.

Comment: Oh so if the conjunct contains a literal with its complement, the entire conjunct can be omitted, together with any other literals in that conjunct? That is the part I seem to have missed - but it does make logical sense. Thank you!